# why is this recursive solution not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

The question is the following :

Write a function called productOfArray which takes in an array of numbers and returns the product of them all.

Why does this solution not work:

```
function productOfArray(arr){
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        return arr[0];
     }
     if (arr.length > 1){
     var last = arr.length - 1
     arr.pop()
     return arr[last] * productOfArray(arr)
}
```

And is there a better way to solve this recursively without altering the array?

Comment: Array reduce is a better solution

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: `console.log(arr[last]); arr.pop(); console.log(arr[last]);`

Comment: Have you tried [debugging it](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a better way to solve this recursively without altering the array?

Honestly, recursion is not the best way to go about this. Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the idiomatic way of handling this:

```
arr.reduce(
    (a, b) => a * b, // apply the operation
    1                // use the identity element for the operation
)                    //   which is the number 1 for multiplication
```

However, since you're asking for how to do it with recursion without modifying the array, here it is:

```js
function productOfArray(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) { //terminal condition
    return 1;             // produce the identity element for multiplication
  }

  return arr[0] //first element
    *           //multiplied by
    productOfArray(arr.slice(1)) //the rest of the elements multiplied
}

const arr1 = [2, 3, 4];
const arr2 = [3, 3, 10];
const arr3 = [5, 3, 7];

console.log("2 * 3 * 4 =", productOfArray(arr1));
console.log("3 * 3 * 10 =", productOfArray(arr2));
console.log("5 * 3 * 7 =", productOfArray(arr3));

console.log("arr1 unchanged:", arr1);
console.log("arr2 unchanged:", arr2);
console.log("arr3 unchanged:", arr3);
```

Using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) makes a new array, so the initial one is untouched:

```js
const input = [2, 3, 4];
const result1 = input.slice(1);
const result2 = result1.slice(1);
const result3 = result2.slice(1);

console.log("result1:", result1);
console.log("result2:", result2);
console.log("result3:", result3);
```

And because we terminate with an array of zero elements, we exit after there is nothing left to multiply. With an input of `[2, 3, 4]` the recursion will effectively evaluate `2 * 3 * 4 * 1`.

Note: this implementation *does* mean that `productOfArray([])` (empty array) produces `1`. Whether this is acceptable or not may vary - it's a nice neutral value. The benefit is that you *do* get to finish the recursion with an empty array, otherwise with a terminal condition of `arr.length === 1`, passing an empty array will result in infinite recursion. Unless it's handled as yet another condition:

```javascript
if (arr.length === 0) {
  return 1; //or zero? Or whatever makes sense
}

if (arr.length === 1) {
  return arr[0];
}
```

However, just handling one more condition basically doubles the code of the function. And assuming you want to return `1` anyway, it's unnecessary code. However, it might be worth doing if you want to consider the product of an empty array to be zero.

Finally, the same logic can be implemented using a [destructuring of the function's parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) instead of using `.slice()`

```js
function productOfArray([head, ...tail]) {
  if (head === undefined) {
    return 1;
  }

  return head * productOfArray(tail);
}

const arr1 = [2, 3, 4];
const arr2 = [3, 3, 10];
const arr3 = [5, 3, 7];

console.log("2 * 3 * 4 =", productOfArray(arr1));
console.log("3 * 3 * 10 =", productOfArray(arr2));
console.log("5 * 3 * 7 =", productOfArray(arr3));

console.log("arr1 unchanged:", arr1);
console.log("arr2 unchanged:", arr2);
console.log("arr3 unchanged:", arr3);
```

As [Scott Sayuet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet) points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470552/why-is-this-recursive-solution-not-working/64471051?noredirect=1#comment114001560_64471051) the above can even be shortened to:

```javascript
const prod = ([x, ...xs] = []) => 
    x == undefined ? 1 : x * prod (xs)
```

Comment: Nice answer!  I want to note that I see no reason for controversy over returning `1` for the empty array.  It is mathematically the correct answer and much simpler to deal with all around.  Also, if the OP is interested in expression style, your last version might also be written as `const prod = ([x, ...xs] = []) => x == undefined ? 1 : x * prod (xs)`

Comment: @ScottSauyet thanks, I hope you don't mind if I add this code to the answer.

Comment: Not at all.  I saw the question, knew that was my answer, and then saw that you'd already written a definitive one.  But variants never hurt.

Answer (score 2):

`arr[last]` will be `undefined` because the number at that index does not exist anymore because of the `pop` call. Also, `pop` will return the item it removes, so you don't need the indexing at all, just use what `pop` returns like so:

```
var last = arr.pop();                   // remove the last number from the array and store it in the variable 'last'
return last * productOfArray(arr);      // use it here
```

Comment: yea I figured something was going wrong there, thanks!

Comment: @sofiat123 you're welcome! Happy coding & learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You are poping before putting it somewhere. Put it in tmp variable and then multiply it.

```js
function productOfArray(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return arr[0];
  }
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    var last = arr.length - 1;
    var tmp = arr[last];
    arr.pop();
    return tmp * productOfArray(arr);
  }
}

console.log(productOfArray([2, 5, 1, 2]));
```